# Textblob return neutral result for all negative comments, using aws glue pyspark job

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-lambda, aws-glue, textblob

I am facing an issue with textblob sentimental analysis. I have written code in pyspark that runs on aws glue spark job. The issue is it returns neutral result for negative comments. I have tried the same code on lambda(with python2.7,python3.6, and python 3.7 ), aws glue pythonshell job, and on my local machine, library works fine on them. but giving neutral results on aws glue spark job.

this code will get the return the result against comments

```
import sys
import boto3
import json
import logging
import sys
import uuid
import json
import imp
import sys
sys.modules["sqlite"] = imp.new_module("sqlite")
sys.modules["sqlite3.dbapi2"] = imp.new_module("sqlite.dbapi2")
from textblob import TextBlob 
import re
import datetime

from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from collections import OrderedDict



boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='us-east-1')

def clean_tweet(tweet): 
''' 
Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special 
characters 
using simple regex statements. 
'''
return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) |(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split()) 


def get_tweet_sentiment(tweet): 
''' 
Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet 
using textblob's sentiment method

print("s",tweet)
analysis = TextBlob(clean_tweet(tweet)) 
print(analysis.sentiment.polarity)
if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0: 
    return 'positive'
elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0: 
    return 'neutral'
else: 
    return 'negative'
```

Comment: if i call this:
    print(get_tweet_sentiment('Disclaimer: Test negative tweet: #Pharma is worst ever pharma Company.'))
it should print "negative" but it returns "neutral"

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the example above.  Your code outputs: ```s Disclaimer: Test negative tweet: #Pharma is worst ever pharma Company.
-0.65
negative```.  Having a 0 polarity score is is pretty much impossible for a normal tweet but that *IS* the output for a blank tweet.  Double check ```tweet``` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: have you tried it on aws glue spark job?

Comment: because this code works fine every where except aws glue etl job.